# How to interpret an InstructionError from solana/web3.js?

Tags: web3.js, error

Hey all I'm getting this error `{"InstructionError": [2, {"Custom": 167}]}` thrown when using `connection.confirmTransaction`.

Thus far I've interpreted what different instruction errors mean through tribal knowledge shared on Discord.

Is there a more official place I could look to find the interpretation for that error code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`InstructionError`s are [a variant of](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/8015aedfdd27a18357d9759c2ff3cad639a3d649/sdk/src/transaction/error.rs#L51-L54) `TransactionError`, a core feature, nothing to do with web3.js specifically.

The first item in the tuple is the index (zero-based) of the instruction which raised the error.

The second item is the actual [`InstructionError`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/8015aedfdd27a18357d9759c2ff3cad639a3d649/sdk/program/src/instruction.rs#L36) `enum` variant.  In your example `Custom` which carries a `u32` error code defined by the program which declared the corresponding instruction.

So the course of action here is to inspect the transaction to determine its third instruction.  Use its program id to identify the project.  Then hope that it is open source, has good docs or someone has reverse engineered the protocol already, so you can lookup the error.

You may be able to take a shortcut and instead infer what happened from the transaction logs if they exist and are informative